# Use PHP to format an input SQL query as HTML?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, pretty-print

What I am looking for is a php function that takes an unformatted query like this:

> $sql = "select name, size from things where color = 'green' order by price asc";

so that it would appear in an HTML page something like this:

```
SELECT
    name, size
FROM
    things
WHERE
    color = 'green'
ORDER BY
    price ASC';
```

There's some code inside phpMyAdmin that does this already, I could look in there I guess!

Comment: You could... What is the question?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the same problem and made a light-weight PHP class to do formatting/syntax highlighting.

https://github.com/jdorn/sql-formatter

I haven't fully tested it with complex queries (sub-selects, unions, etc.), but it seems to work pretty well for common cases.

To get fully accurate results, you really need a full SQL parser like phpMyAdmin uses, but that uses 10,000+ lines of code spread out over many files and is probably overkill for simple debugging.

Comment: beautiful! using in my sql builder to display the results. works perfectly, just plug in and it works

Comment: Great! Greetings from Colombia.

Comment: Great ! I wish I could give more than one up-votes. I wonder this answer is not accepted though.

Comment: lower response from Ashish Makhija has the same functionality in single file just without a color

Answer (score 13):

```
function getFormattedSQL($sql_raw)
{
 if( empty($sql_raw) || !is_string($sql_raw) )
 {
  return false;
 }

 $sql_reserved_all = array (
     'ACCESSIBLE', 'ACTION', 'ADD', 'AFTER', 'AGAINST', 'AGGREGATE', 'ALGORITHM', 'ALL', 'ALTER', 'ANALYSE', 'ANALYZE', 'AND', 'AS', 'ASC',
     'AUTOCOMMIT', 'AUTO_INCREMENT', 'AVG_ROW_LENGTH', 'BACKUP', 'BEGIN', 'BETWEEN', 'BINLOG', 'BOTH', 'BY', 'CASCADE', 'CASE', 'CHANGE', 'CHANGED',
     'CHARSET', 'CHECK', 'CHECKSUM', 'COLLATE', 'COLLATION', 'COLUMN', 'COLUMNS', 'COMMENT', 'COMMIT', 'COMMITTED', 'COMPRESSED', 'CONCURRENT', 
     'CONSTRAINT', 'CONTAINS', 'CONVERT', 'CREATE', 'CROSS', 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP', 'DATABASE', 'DATABASES', 'DAY', 'DAY_HOUR', 'DAY_MINUTE', 
     'DAY_SECOND', 'DEFINER', 'DELAYED', 'DELAY_KEY_WRITE', 'DELETE', 'DESC', 'DESCRIBE', 'DETERMINISTIC', 'DISTINCT', 'DISTINCTROW', 'DIV',
     'DO', 'DROP', 'DUMPFILE', 'DUPLICATE', 'DYNAMIC', 'ELSE', 'ENCLOSED', 'END', 'ENGINE', 'ENGINES', 'ESCAPE', 'ESCAPED', 'EVENTS', 'EXECUTE',
     'EXISTS', 'EXPLAIN', 'EXTENDED', 'FAST', 'FIELDS', 'FILE', 'FIRST', 'FIXED', 'FLUSH', 'FOR', 'FORCE', 'FOREIGN', 'FROM', 'FULL', 'FULLTEXT',
     'FUNCTION', 'GEMINI', 'GEMINI_SPIN_RETRIES', 'GLOBAL', 'GRANT', 'GRANTS', 'GROUP', 'HAVING', 'HEAP', 'HIGH_PRIORITY', 'HOSTS', 'HOUR', 'HOUR_MINUTE',
     'HOUR_SECOND', 'IDENTIFIED', 'IF', 'IGNORE', 'IN', 'INDEX', 'INDEXES', 'INFILE', 'INNER', 'INSERT', 'INSERT_ID', 'INSERT_METHOD', 'INTERVAL',
     'INTO', 'INVOKER', 'IS', 'ISOLATION', 'JOIN', 'KEY', 'KEYS', 'KILL', 'LAST_INSERT_ID', 'LEADING', 'LEFT', 'LEVEL', 'LIKE', 'LIMIT', 'LINEAR',               
     'LINES', 'LOAD', 'LOCAL', 'LOCK', 'LOCKS', 'LOGS', 'LOW_PRIORITY', 'MARIA', 'MASTER', 'MASTER_CONNECT_RETRY', 'MASTER_HOST', 'MASTER_LOG_FILE',
     'MASTER_LOG_POS', 'MASTER_PASSWORD', 'MASTER_PORT', 'MASTER_USER', 'MATCH', 'MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR', 'MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR',
     'MAX_ROWS', 'MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR', 'MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS', 'MEDIUM', 'MERGE', 'MINUTE', 'MINUTE_SECOND', 'MIN_ROWS', 'MODE', 'MODIFY',
     'MONTH', 'MRG_MYISAM', 'MYISAM', 'NAMES', 'NATURAL', 'NOT', 'NULL', 'OFFSET', 'ON', 'OPEN', 'OPTIMIZE', 'OPTION', 'OPTIONALLY', 'OR',
     'ORDER', 'OUTER', 'OUTFILE', 'PACK_KEYS', 'PAGE', 'PARTIAL', 'PARTITION', 'PARTITIONS', 'PASSWORD', 'PRIMARY', 'PRIVILEGES', 'PROCEDURE',
     'PROCESS', 'PROCESSLIST', 'PURGE', 'QUICK', 'RAID0', 'RAID_CHUNKS', 'RAID_CHUNKSIZE', 'RAID_TYPE', 'RANGE', 'READ', 'READ_ONLY',            
     'READ_WRITE', 'REFERENCES', 'REGEXP', 'RELOAD', 'RENAME', 'REPAIR', 'REPEATABLE', 'REPLACE', 'REPLICATION', 'RESET', 'RESTORE', 'RESTRICT',
     'RETURN', 'RETURNS', 'REVOKE', 'RIGHT', 'RLIKE', 'ROLLBACK', 'ROW', 'ROWS', 'ROW_FORMAT', 'SECOND', 'SECURITY', 'SELECT', 'SEPARATOR',
     'SERIALIZABLE', 'SESSION', 'SET', 'SHARE', 'SHOW', 'SHUTDOWN', 'SLAVE', 'SONAME', 'SOUNDS', 'SQL', 'SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL', 'SQL_BIG_RESULT',
     'SQL_BIG_SELECTS', 'SQL_BIG_TABLES', 'SQL_BUFFER_RESULT', 'SQL_CACHE', 'SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS', 'SQL_LOG_BIN', 'SQL_LOG_OFF',
     'SQL_LOG_UPDATE', 'SQL_LOW_PRIORITY_UPDATES', 'SQL_MAX_JOIN_SIZE', 'SQL_NO_CACHE', 'SQL_QUOTE_SHOW_CREATE', 'SQL_SAFE_UPDATES',
     'SQL_SELECT_LIMIT', 'SQL_SLAVE_SKIP_COUNTER', 'SQL_SMALL_RESULT', 'SQL_WARNINGS', 'START', 'STARTING', 'STATUS', 'STOP', 'STORAGE',
     'STRAIGHT_JOIN', 'STRING', 'STRIPED', 'SUPER', 'TABLE', 'TABLES', 'TEMPORARY', 'TERMINATED', 'THEN', 'TO', 'TRAILING', 'TRANSACTIONAL',    
     'TRUNCATE', 'TYPE', 'TYPES', 'UNCOMMITTED', 'UNION', 'UNIQUE', 'UNLOCK', 'UPDATE', 'USAGE', 'USE', 'USING', 'VALUES', 'VARIABLES',
     'VIEW', 'WHEN', 'WHERE', 'WITH', 'WORK', 'WRITE', 'XOR', 'YEAR_MONTH'
 );

 $sql_skip_reserved_words = array('AS', 'ON', 'USING');
 $sql_special_reserved_words = array('(', ')');

 $sql_raw = str_replace("\n", " ", $sql_raw);

 $sql_formatted = "";

 $prev_word = "";
 $word = "";

 for( $i=0, $j = strlen($sql_raw); $i < $j; $i++ )
 {
  $word .= $sql_raw[$i];

  $word_trimmed = trim($word);

  if($sql_raw[$i] == " " || in_array($sql_raw[$i], $sql_special_reserved_words))
  {
   $word_trimmed = trim($word);

   $trimmed_special = false;

   if( in_array($sql_raw[$i], $sql_special_reserved_words) )
   {
    $word_trimmed = substr($word_trimmed, 0, -1);
    $trimmed_special = true;
   }

   $word_trimmed = strtoupper($word_trimmed);

   if( in_array($word_trimmed, $sql_reserved_all) && !in_array($word_trimmed, $sql_skip_reserved_words) )
   {
    if(in_array($prev_word, $sql_reserved_all))
    {
     $sql_formatted .= '<b>'.strtoupper(trim($word)).'</b>'.'&nbsp;';
    }
    else
    {
     $sql_formatted .= '<br/>&nbsp;';
     $sql_formatted .= '<b>'.strtoupper(trim($word)).'</b>'.'&nbsp;';
    }

    $prev_word = $word_trimmed;
    $word = "";
   }
   else
   {
    $sql_formatted .= trim($word).'&nbsp;';

    $prev_word = $word_trimmed;
    $word = "";
   }
  }
 }

 $sql_formatted .= trim($word);

 return $sql_formatted;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but how is this a good formatter, each reserved word on a separate line it is in my opinion not the best formatting eg
`
SELECT x
FROM x
JOIN ON
WHERE A
UNION
SELECT x
FROM x
JOIN ON
WHERE A
`

Answer (score 7):

Using phpMyAdmin is quite straight forward:

```
require 'libraries/common.inc.php';

$sql= "select * from test";
$parsed_sql = PMA_SQP_parse($sql);    
echo PMA_SQP_formatHtml($parsed_sql);
```

Add a stylesheet to enable syntax highlighting. If you read a bit in the [sqlparser documentation](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/phpdoc/phpMyAdmin/_libraries---sqlparser.lib.php.html) you'll find some other function for different formatting types.

Only thing is that phpMyAdmin is somewhat large to only use SQL parsing, so you might want to strip all other functionalities...

Comment: I tried this, but found it far from straight forward, and gave up in the end.

Comment: I tried the example myself (by creating a test.php) in the phpmyadmin directory and it worked for me.

Comment: OK, I now got the script to work by saving it in /usr/share/phpmyadmin/ and opening it in the browser from /phpmyadmin/. As you say, I'll have to dig around in the documentation to get the nice formatting. Its not quite as straight forward as I hoped, but thanks very much for the pointers.

Answer (score 4):

```
function sql_format($query) {
  $keywords = array("select", "from", "where", "order by", "group by", "insert into", "update","SET", ",");
  foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
      if (preg_match("/($keyword *)/i", ",", $matches)) {
        $query = str_replace($matches[1],strtoupper($matches[1]) . "<br/>&nbsp;&nbsp;  ", $query);  
      }
    else if(preg_match("/($keyword *)/i", $query, $matches)) {
      $query = str_replace($matches[1],"<br>".strtoupper($matches[1]) . "<br/>&nbsp;  ", $query);
    }
  }
  return $query;
}
```

Comment: thank you, beautiful formatter,  I didnt like each keyword on separate line only - as Iosif, almost like Jeremy Dorn upper library

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's any freely available code that does this within PECL or similar - which is a pity, as it would be quite a neat little utility. (Albeit only with fairly limited uses.)

As such, you're answered you own question - phpMyAdmin is probably a good first port of call.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work - add any other SQL keywords you want to parse:

```
function sql_format($query) {
  $keywords = array("select", "from", "where", "order by", "group by", "insert into", "update");
  foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    if (preg_match("/($keyword *)/i", $query, $matches)) {
      $query = str_replace($matches[1], "\n" . strtoupper($matches[1]) . "\n  ", $query);
    }
  }
  return $query;
}
```

Comment: This is subject to some possible bugs.

Comment: Sure it is... it's just a starting suggestion :)

Comment: Oh, and wrap the return string in "<pre>...</pre>" to display with indentation in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

May be This is what you want: http://www.orczhou.com/sqlparser/  PHP SQL Format